How to set constraint in dockview js library
How can I set constraints for the Dockview group at the moment it is rendered? The only example Dockview provides is setting constraints via a button, and they apply only when constraints are changed. How can I control the width and height of the rendered group precisely?
I tried using api to set constraints in component directly but it didn't work.
TermostatForm = (props) => {
    props.api.group.api.setConstraints({
        maximumWidth: 300,
        maximumHeight: 300,
    });


Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
